# What are AudienceRestrictionConditions in KentorAuthServices?

Tags: kentor-authservices

Im working with Kentor Auth Services. Im getting an error when testing the SAML integration using Kentor Sample Idp

> ID1035: The SAML Assertion did not contain any
>   AudienceRestrictionConditions. To accept assertions without
>   AudienceRestrictionConditions, set
>   SecurityTokenHandlerConfiguration.AudienceRestriction.AudienceMode to
>   AudienceUriMode.Never.

Can someone let me know why im getting this error. Also I'm seeing a field called Audience. I have left it as blank since im not sure what needs to be added there I have tried adding 'Never', but on checking the source it seems like it requires an Uri.

Can someone please let me know what needs to be given in this field? 
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default WIF/AuthServices checks the Audience restriction in the SAML response. To handle the error you need to do either of:

- Put the EntityId of the SP in the Audience field.
- Set `spOptions.SystemIdentityModelIdentityConfiguration.AudienceRestriction.AudienceMode = AudienceUriMode.Never;`.